# CakePHP 3 Ajax Call Performance issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

We have done the below code element (text posting by ajax) in cakephp 2.5.

Later, when we changed to cakephp 3, it seems like the performance of the function is diminished to a very noticeable extend in comparison with version 2.5 (mainly execution time has increased from 250 ms to 1.4s)

```
// ajax call to save post
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: baseUrl + 'posts/add',
     data: data,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(response, status) {
         if(!response.success) {
              alert('An unexpected error has occurred!');
         }else{
              append_post(response.post_id);
         }
     },
     error: function(response, status) {
         console.log(response);
         alert('An unexpected error has occurred!!');
     }
});
```

This is the php code:

```
//posts/add  function
public function add()
{   
    $this->layout ='ajax';
    $this->autoRender = FALSE;
    $post = $this->Posts->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $status['success'] = FALSE;
        $post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->data);

        if ($this->Posts->save($post)) {
             $status['success'] = True; 
             $status['post_id'] = $post->id; 
        }
        $this->response->body(json_encode($status));
        return $this->response;
   }
}
```

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? We cannot profile your app for you, that's what _you_ have to do in order to figure out where the time is spent (try XDebug or similar tools). Once you know that, check back with that info in case you cannot solve the problem on your own.

Comment: Comparing the performance between cakephp 2.5 & 3, 3 seems to be a little laggy,  if any correction in the code whatever i have provided would solve the problem? or does that seems to be a trade of for somebody choosing cakephp 3 ??  it seems like TTFB is  taking more time.

Comment: There is pretty much no room for optimizations in that code snippet, and there is no known general performance problem with CakePHP 3 (except for maybe when datasource metadata caching is disabled), even on a rather slow local testserver in a vagrant machine (virtualbox) with debug mode and XDebug enabled, I get an average TTFB of 241ms. So again, please profile where exactly the time is spent, having people shoot in the dark isn't overly effective.